# Intellij - Debugger not working in maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I came across an issue where I am not able to debug a maven sprint boot REST API application in IntelliJ. The application starts up but won't stop at any breakpoint.

Additionally when I stop the debugger I see below lines in the log, but I can see that the java process never terminates and when I start the app the 2nd time it fails because the server port 8080 is still in use.

```
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53020', transport: 'socket'
Process finished with exit code -1
```

In the IntelliJ logs at C:\Users\Bernhard.IdeaIC2017.3\system\log I see the following error.

```
2017-12-15 07:22:30,761 [  11899]   INFO - .server.BuildMessageDispatcher - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably wrap the value of that argument in quotations. The parser that reads the entire command line string is probably choking because of the -D arg within a -D arg.

clean package -Drun.profiles=dev-us-east-1 -Drun.jvmArguments=**"-Denvironment=dev"** -DskipTests spring-boot:run

Comment: Hi Jaraon, good oberservation. I did have the "-Denvironment=dev" in double quotes. I believe Stackoverflow seems to have removed them in my copy paste...

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found that the problem is with my Maven Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ. The command line I use to start the spring boot rest api is

```
clean package -Drun.profiles=dev-us-east-1 -Drun.jvmArguments=-Denvironment=dev -DskipTests spring-boot:run
```

It appears that the `-Drun.jvmArguments=-Denvironment=dev` java command line property is the culprit. When I remove it the break points work again.